# Set text inside elements added via .createDocumentFragment()

Tags: javascript

I have a function set up to create a specific number of elements, add them to a fragment, then append that fragment to a div. What I'm trying to do is set the text for each of those elements independent of one another. Here's the code:

```
function banner(element){

    var p, fragment= document.createDocumentFragment();

    for (var i=0; i<8; i++){
        p= document.createElement('p');
        fragment.appendChild(p);
    }
    element.appendChild(fragment);
}

banner(modal);
```

So i need each `<p>` node to have different text. Oh, and please no jQuery answers here.

[JSBin Link](http://jsbin.com/iwinup/edit#javascript,html,live)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want `document.createTextNode("Text goes here")`, which you then `appendChild()` to the `<p>`:

```
function banner(element){

    var p, t, fragment= document.createDocumentFragment();

    for (var i=0; i<8; i++){
        p= document.createElement('p');
        t = document.createTextNode("Your text goes here");
        p.appendChild(t);
        fragment.appendChild(p);
    }
    element.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a coded solution? As it is this won't work for me.

Comment: Ok, but how do I say p[0] is equal to textnode 1, p[1] is equal to textnode 2, etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish at this point.  You set the text for each node when you create it in the loop.  If you want it to do different, you supply a different string to the `.createTextNode()` each time.

Comment: Each <p> should have different text nodes. So the line t= document.createTextNode("Your text goes here"); will create the same text node 8 times. p.appendChild(t) is appending that same text node 8 times- one for each <p>. I need 8 different text nodes appended to each <p> one at a time starting from index 0 to 7.

Comment: Okay, so have you tried changing the argument to the `.createTextNode()` to what you need? Perhaps a string a concatenating whatever text you want with the loop index?  At this point it should be a rather elementary coding exercise to do so.       And no, it's not appending the same text node 8 times.  Each time the loop executes, it's creating a _new_ paragraph node, appending a _new_ text node, then appending the paragraph node to the fragment.  It just looks the same because each text node it created with the exact same text.

Comment: Solved it by creating an array before the loop and assigning the different text values for each array index. Then I just referenced it in the loop via: t= document.createTextNode(text[i]);